# Twitter Bootstrap: Change column amount by layout width

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have some narrow content that I would like to take up 3 columns for large desktop (>=1200px), but only 2 columns for default (980px-1199px)?

Is this possible with Twitter Bootstrap? 
Would prefer not to use javascript...

Answer (score 0):

I ended up manually writing the css rules for the floats i.e:

```
li {
  width: 33%; float:left;
}
@media (max-width: 1200px) {
  width:50%;
}
```

Comment: You will not get 2 columns like this. You will get 2 followed by 1 + 0 (white space). If you have 4 columns, this approach will work.